# How to pass sql where clauses from Form to Php and securly execute on database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have Laravel application in Laravel 8.

Let's say I have a form for filtering records. Inside this form I have field called **query**. User can type there sql where caluse for example **(`a` > 5 and `b` >= 35 and (`x` == "a" || `created_at` > "2021-07-25"))**.

User can use only >, >=, <, <=, == and !=.

What is the best way to secure an application against SQL Injection in this situtaion?

**Edit:**
I found this package https://github.com/rexshijaku/sql-to-laravel-builder

I used it and it work perfectly. This package returns laravel eloquent query as a string. So to workaround it i had to eval("return $query;");. I also copy this repository to my application and made changes, so this package returns only WHERE calueses, so I can apply these where's into certain query. So eval looks like
**eval("return App\Models\MyModel::query()->$query")**
And it returns a MyModel query builder.

Comment: This way very dangerous. The best way is create combo box for select data and check manually on side server

Comment: The best way is not to allow the user to construct the SQL directly at all. Instead provide a UI where they select some options and your PHP code then constructs a parameterised query based on that information.

Comment: What about making a dynamic form which sends the query in parts to the server (e.g. `[ 'where' => [ [ 'field' => 'id', 'comperator' => '=', 'value' => 1 ] ], 'fields' => ['id', 'name'], 'table' => 'users' ]`)

Comment: In my task I have request that, user should have possibility to construct its own sql. 
I didn't mention that this is API.

Comment: If the requirement is that the user can make their own SQL and execute it, then there is nothing you can do, you have to accept the risk that they might write something malicious. I suggest only giving access to carefully vetted, trusted users.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel eloquent and query builder both protect you against sql injection, EXCEPT that it is possible to create a RAW sql statement. It is not recommended that you do this, but people do. When they cannot work out the correct query builder methods to do, they will resort to using raw. Raw queries combined with string concatenation are a bad sign.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-and-sql-injections